# Is it possible to create a property of type BindingBase?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have a user control in which I added a dependency property named "ImageBinding" of type BindingBase, my question is How can I initialize this property in Xaml ?
for example, if I have a dependency property named Value of type int, in xaml I initialize it like this :

```
Value="1"
```

or

```
Value={Binding Age}
```

but what if the type of my property is BindingBase ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For example `GridViewColumn` has [`DisplayMemberBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `BindingBase` type but it's normal property (not `DependencyProperty`). But I don't understand what is your problem. Are you having problem creating such property?

Comment: You shouldn't really have any need to extend the `BindingBase` class. Perhaps if you let us know what you were *actually* trying to do, we could suggest a better solution.

Comment: You can only have a normal CLR property - i.e. it can't be a DependencyProperty. Otherwise the framework will see the Binding and try to apply the Binding to provide the value for the DP.

Comment: thanks @AndrewS , I changed ImageBinding to a CLR property and it works !

Answer (score 1):

I changed ImageBinding to a CLR property as AndrewS suggested and it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was creating an AttachedProperty, so this meant that a normal CLR property was not possible.

The trick is to declare the DependencyProperty type as BindingExpressionBase rather than BindingBase.

You can then get to BindingBase from the [BindingExpressionBase.ParentBindingBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.parentbindingbase?view=netframework-4.8) property.

```
public static class Example
{
    public static BindingExpressionBase GetMyBinding(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (BindingExpressionBase)obj.GetValue(MyBindingProperty);
    }
    public static void SetMyBinding(DependencyObject obj, BindingExpressionBase value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyBindingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            name:               "MyBinding",
            propertyType:       typeof(BindingExpressionBase),
            ownerType:          typeof(Example),
            defaultMetadata:    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
}

DependencyObject obj = ...;
BindingBase bb = Example.GetMyBinding(obj)?.ParentBindingBase;
```